# Remove slices from array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, slice

I have a PHP array and I want to remove slices of elements with the following rule: when an element has `visible=0`, I want remove the element and the following `elements` after it, no matter if they are visible or not.

In this example, I would like to remove `two`, `three`, `four`, `six` and `seven`

```
$categories = array(
              array('id'=>'one','visible'=>1,'elements'=>2),
              array('id'=>'two','visible'=>0,'elements'=>2),
              array('id'=>'three','visible'=>0,'elements'=>1),
              array('id'=>'four','visible'=>1,'elements'=>3),
              array('id'=>'five','visible'=>1,'elements'=>2),
              array('id'=>'six','visible'=>0,'elements'=>1),
              array('id'=>'seven','visible'=>1,'elements'=>3),
              array('id'=>'eight','visible'=>1,'elements'=>2)
              );
```

I've tried the following snippet

```
foreach($categories as $i=>$data)
{
    if($data['visible']==0)
    {
        array_splice($categories, $i, $data['elements']);
    }
}
```

This is my expected result after slicing and the actual result

- expected: `one`, `five`, `eight`
- actual:   `one`, `four`, `five`, `seven`, `eight`

What am I missing?

Comment: if 3 has got visible = 0, you shouldn't expect the four in your output... am I wrong?

Comment: Regarding your code, I think it does not work because you change the array structure inside the `foreach`. The `array_splice()` confuses the `foreach` when it comes to enter the next loop. I would use a plain `for(;;)` and copy the desired items into a new array.

Comment: yea your expected outcome will occur if u set the visible => 0 for id => 7

Comment: @Masiorama: yep sorry, fixed it. Thanks for point it out.

Comment: there is still another error (six)... you should check again the data, and the rule too, I guess, just to be sure.

Comment: Shouldn't `eight` also be removed, since you want to "remove the element and the following elements after it"? Or is that a typo and `elements` should be `element`?

Comment: the problem is, you are modifying your existing array. since you remove values, the array size changes and if you access it with the old index, you'll get wrong results.

Comment: @Masiorama: yep, thanks again. Fixed (hopefully for the last time).

Comment: @IkoTikashi: 8 should not be removed, since it doesn't have `visible=0` and it's not involved in removal from previous (6 has `elements=1`, this means that only 6,7 should be removed)

Comment: here is a little [demonstration](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b57c6a593402712dcfbc6d5b95352ee4bbee8a34) why it's bad to change the array while looping through.

Comment: I was wrong about the `array_splice()` confusing the `foreach()`. Your solution works but only if you remove the correct number of items. And that number is **`1 + `**`$data['elements']` because the current item itself needs to be removed too. I updated my answer with your code fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run through `$categories` using a simple `for()` loop, copy the visible items to a new list (`$cat`), skip the not visible items and the specified number of items that follows them:

```
// Generate the filtered list here
$cat = array();

$count = count($categories);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i ++) {
    $data = $categories[$i];
    if ($data['visible']) {
       // Copy visible item
       $cat[] = $data;
    } else {
       // Do not copy and skip the specified number of extra items
       $i += $data['elements'];
    }
}

echo("Expected: one, five, eight\n");
echo('Actual  : '.implode(', ', array_column($cat, 'id'))."\n");
```

#### Update

Your solution works too if you remove the correct number of items using `array_splice()`: they are `1 + $data['elements']`; `1` is the item at index `$i` and the next `$data['elements']` items.

```
foreach($categories as $i=>$data)
{
    if($data['visible']==0)
    {
        array_splice($categories, $i, 1 + $data['elements']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, so glad to hear about that. Thanks for the help (and at least, +1 for the update)!

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy:

```
$length  = count($categories);
$results = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    # just skip!
    if ($categories[ $i ]['visible'] == 0) {
        $i = ( $i + $categories[ $i ]['elements'] );        
    } else {
        array_push($results, $categories[$i]);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of alternatives more, using `array_column` (>php5.5.0) and `array_filter`:

```
foreach (array_column($categories, 'visible') as $k => $v) {
    if (!$v) {
        $categories[$k] = $categories[$k++] = null;
    }
}

$result = array_filter($categories);
var_dump($result);
```

Or with `array_walk`

```
array_walk(array_column($categories, 'visible'), function ($v, $k) use (&$categories) {
    if (!$v) {
        $categories[$k] = $categories[$k++] = null;
    }
});

$result = array_filter($categories);
var_dump($result);
```